# my system is not booting

Tags: boot

I have installed updates and then my system hanged. SO I forced to shutdown. It restarted and worked fine. Again, it hanged for a while so I forced to shutdown by pressing the power button. restarted and it is going to emergency mode and asking me to repair. it is simply terminal mode. I don't have any idea to repair.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the Elementary OS again. I installed all updates and restarted the system. Now, it works fine. However, appcentre may hang and i chose force quit option , then start the appcentre again. Thank god, it is working. I have spent lot of hours on this. I installed wine and installed chessmaster program , it is working. I could not install chessmaster in windows 10. SO, i chose linux and I found elementary os in one webpage. Now, everything works.